# what do you recommend to start a project like this? StartUp teespring vistaprint

Tags: customization, startup, js-fancyproductdesigner

I'm trying to make a startup business, something like vistaprint or teespring

I'm not a programmer (not yet, learning right now, but I do know use wordpress) but I found a way to make something simillary using > demo.lumise.com

How hard is to make something like this from scratch?

I need a lot of customization from about Lumise plugin (woocommerce) or php script for this idea , so I need building from zero I guess.

What do you recommend me?

Anything helps me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are not a programmer and you are not wordpress expert right ?

So don't try to compete with King Theme to develop something like Lumise from Zero. That sounds unrealistic

If I was you, the best thing I can do is: I will invest $59 to buy Lumise. Because It is PHP so you can read and analyze its code, then customize additional features.

No one on Stack Overflow can estimate for you How hard it is, because they don't know What do you want to customize

To sum up for this question, I think the best way is buy that tools and try to customize your features from exists one.

Ah, If budget is not problem why don't you discuss with them to customize for you ? I see there is custom plan on their pricing

That's sure help you save more time & money